# Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: No such variant in enum MultiSignature

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

Hi I am getting the below error in polkadot-js, when I am trying to transfer the balance from Alice to Dave (or any other transfer).

Error :
balances.transferKeepAlive
1002: Verification Error: Execution: Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: No such variant in enum MultiSignature: RuntimeApi, Execution: Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: No such variant in enum MultiSignature

Please refer the screen shot in the below :
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9b5a.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some data types on your UI, adding this in developer settings will do the job.

```
{
  "Address": "MultiAddress",
  "LookupSource": "MultiAddress"
}
```

https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ#the-node-returns-a-could-not-convert-error-on-send

Comment: I added in the developer settings but it did not worked, for me!

Comment: settings > developer , then save, and it is not working ?

Comment: These types get cached by the browser, something that could be helpful would be clearing cookies + cache or using an incognito config where this data is not locally maintained.
So you have less problems when customizing this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "Address": "MultiAddress",
  "LookupSource": "MultiAddress"
}
```

Worked for me on the Substrate - Forkless Upgrade a Chain tutorial:  https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/forkless-upgrade/sudo-upgrade

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9944#/settings/developer -> Settings - Developer - change the JSON to match the above -> Save, that's it.