# Print "Hello Substrate" in exercise Printing to Node Log does not print to the node log?

Tags: rust, substrate

I am new to substrate and rust programming (I am currently on ch. 14 of the book).  I have gone through some of the tutorials and wanted to begin going through substrate recipes.  However I am stuck at the very first one.  Is there anything that I need to change with regard to the code.  If so that is not clear to me.  I checked the cargo.toml files and everything seems to be already set up to get the phrase "Hello World" to print to the node log.  Also, isn't printing to the node log the same as printing to the terminal screen that you launched the target executable from?  I am not seeing anything there.

Answer (score 1):

Before you get into the recipes, it is highly recommended to start with the [substrate developer hub tutorials](https://substrate.dev/tutorials/) to get started. The first four (left to right from the top) are best to get a sense of basics of substrate development, then head back to [recipes](https://substrate.dev/recipes/) and the more actively maintained **successor to them: [How-to Guides](https://substrate.dev/substrate-how-to-guides/)** to get specific things implemented in your runtime & node host.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I have been through all of them.  So, I am assuming that the node log just prints to the terminal console, correct?

Comment: Okay not all I have been through these.

Create your first Substrate chain.
Forkless upgrade a Chain.
Add pallets to your runtime and publish pallets.
Build a PoE decentralized application.
Add the Contracts Pallet to the runtime.

Comment: Most surely you would need to initialize the logger by addding this line
`debug::RuntimeLogger::init();` before logging.

If that is still not working, I would say to use [log crate](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.14/log/index.html) for your dispatchables instead

Comment: I initialized the logger as you recommended but still nothing is printed to the terminal console.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

What is unclear to me is that it seems that this should work without any changes to the code, i.e. clone the recipes repo build and run, it should be showing up.

My other question is, where is the node log?  Isn't that just the terminal where you launched it from?

Comment: So I realized that this is an extrinsic that I am trying to call but when I connect to it via polkadot.js and call the extrinsic, I get the following error -
Failed to submit extrinsic: Extrinsic verification error: Runtime error: Execution failed: ApiError("Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: Could not decode `MultiSignature`, variant doesn't exist")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114949/could-not-convert-parameter-tx-between-node-and-runtime-no-such-variant-in-en