# Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: Could not decode `Call::Assets.0`:Could not decode

Tags: substrate

```
Execution failed: ApiError("Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: Could not decode `Call::Assets.0`:\n\tCould not decode `Call::create.3`:\n\t\tNot enough data to fill buffer\n")
```

Runtime Implementation In Substrate node template v`pallet-assets = { default-features = false, version = '3.0.0' }`

```
parameter_types! {
pub const AssetDepositBase: u64 = 1;
pub const AssetDepositPerZombie: u64 = 1;
pub const StringLimit: u32 = 50;
pub const MetadataDepositBase: u64 = 1;
pub const MetadataDepositPerByte: u64 = 1;
pub const AssetDepositPerZombie: Balance = 2 * 7;
pub const AssetDeposit: Balance = 2 * 7 ;
pub const ApprovalDeposit: Balance = 2 * 7 ;
}

impl pallet_assets::pallet::Config for Runtime {

type Event= Event;
type Balance= Balance;
type AssetId= u32;
type Currency = Balances;
type ForceOrigin = frame_system::EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
type StringLimit = StringLimit;  
type AssetDepositBase=AssetDepositBase;
type AssetDepositPerZombie= AssetDepositPerZombie;
type MetadataDepositBase = MetadataDepositBase;
type MetadataDepositPerByte = MetadataDepositPerByte;
type WeightInfo = pallet_assets::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;

}
```

I am calling the extrinsic from polkadot.js.org (localnode)
In Types using `{ "Address": "MultiAddress", "LookupSource": "MultiAddress" }`
Error Is Not Releated to types MultiAddress, the error is about Call::Assets.0  , I am calling the assets::create extrinsics and all other are working perfectly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not convert parameter \`tx\` between node and runtime: No such variant in enum MultiSignature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114949/could-not-convert-parameter-tx-between-node-and-runtime-no-such-variant-in-en)

Comment: I faced a similar issue. Ensure that the runtime variables in the chain_spec refer to the runtime you're currently using

Answer (score 0):

Close to a duplicate of may other questions here, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114949/could-not-convert-parameter-tx-between-node-and-runtime-no-such-variant-in-en).

You need to set the types used in your chain in you `polkadot.js` API consuming apps: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.extend

Comment: I already have used multiaddress inside my types